GitLab - How to reuse registry image for multiple branches without rebuilding?
I have master and production branches and I currently create MR from master into production. This triggers pipelines and registry image is republished even if the commit hash is the same.
I understand that docker uses caches etc. but is there a way I could skip publishing pipelines and reuse the exact registry image from master for production if commit hash is the same in both branches?

how about just if on master: then upload; else don't upload in pseudocode? What do you mean by "reuse"?
